# passing linq anonymous result to iqueryable object for another query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables (tbPerson and tbDataLog) where I need to return Id from one table (tbPerson) after checking certain conditions on both. After this, this result should be passed to another query. My first query returns the Id (primary key of a table) successfully and I need to pass these ids to another query so that it return me data based upon these Id. I also has an IQueryable type base object to check certain conditions to fetch data.

```
IQueryable<tbPerson> dataset
```

and I cannot changes this from Iqueryable to other as it will break other part of the code)

My first linq statement:

```
  public static IQueryable<LogResults> GetResultsForYes()
    {
        Databasename ents = new Databasename();
        var ids = (from f in ents.tbPerson
                   join g in ents.tbDataLog
                   on f.InfoID equals g.RefId
                   where g.Tag == "subscribed" && g.OldValue == "No" && g.Action == "Modified"
                   select new LogResults { _LogID = f.Id }).OrderBy(x => x._LogID);
        return ids;
    }

public class LogResults
    {
        public int _LogID { get; set; }
    }
```

I access my result something like this where I can see in debugger all the Ids.

```
IQueryable<LogResults> log = GetResultsForYes();
```

Problem comes, when I tried to get records from tbPerson based upon these returned Id.

```
dataset=log.where(x=>x._LogID != 0);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast)?

Any suggestions or some other good approach is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
IQueryable<tbPerson> dataset=log.where(x=>x._LogID != 0);
```

The result of log.where(x=>x._LogID != 0) is an `IQueryable<LogResults>`, and you are trying to assign this result to *dataset* of type `IQueryable<tbPerson>`, two diferent types.

EDIT:
I see you make a join to get the tbPerson ids, and then you do a second query to get the persons. You could get the persons in the first join.

I just modify your code:

```
IQueryable<tbPerson> persons = from person in ents.tbPerson
                       join g in ents.tbDataLog
                       on person.InfoID equals g.RefId
                       where g.Tag == "subscribed" && g.OldValue == "No" && g.Action == "Modified"
                       select person;
```

Answer (score 0):

I love this thing about stackoverflow. when we write questions we force our brain to think more deeply and after 30 mins of posting this question, I solved it in a simple way. Sometimes we overcomplicated things!

```
var ids = (from f in ents.tbPerson
                       join g in ents.tbDataLog
                       on f.InfoID equals g.RefId
                       where g.Tag == "subscribed" && g.OldValue == "No" && g.Action == "Modified"
                       select new { f.Id }).ToArray();

            var allId = ids.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
            dataset = dataset.Where(x => allId.Contains(x.Id));
```

@ankit_sharma : I have not tested yours but will give a try and come back to you. Thanks for giving time and effort.